# Displaying an int variable in TextBox/Label in Visual C#

Tags: c#, variables, visual-studio-2013

I am creating my first C# project, but I can't find a way to display an integer variable in a TextBox or Label. I am using visual C# and Visual Studio 2013.

I have been using C++ for quite a while and I would intuitively use 'cout', but I have no idea where to put fe:  `textBox4.text = cal` (where cal is variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I have no idea where to put fe: textBox4.text = cal (where cal is
>   variable).

You should put this code inside of a **method**.It can be **Form_Load** event, or a `Button` click, for example add a button to your form with designer (drag and drop from toolbox),double click your button and put this code inside of your button click event:

```
textBox4.Text = cal.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

**Problem :** you can only Assign `String` to the TextBox `Text` property.

**Solution :** convert your `cal` variable into String using `ToString()` function and then assign it to the TextBox `Text` property.

Replace This:

```
textBox4.text = cal;
```

With This:

```
textBox4.Text = cal.ToString();
```

Comment: Where should I put it?

Comment: @user3258245 When do you want to change the textbox's text?

Comment: When I put that into that property, I can see that inscription ("textBox4.Text = cal.ToString();") instead of 'cal' variable.

Comment: @user3258245: sorry i didn't get you.

Answer (score 3):

Use one of these *forms*:

```
textBox4.Text = cal.ToString();
textBox4.Text = "" + cal;
textBox4.Text = string.Format("{0}", cal);
```

The last is the best for flexibilty, as shown here with some decorations:

```
textBox4.Text = string.Format("[CELL: {0}]", cal);
```

If there aren't any decorations the `string.Format()` will have an unnecessary overhead that can be avoided by the first *form*.

For readability `string.Format()` should be prefered over concatenating strings (second *form*). What you can't do with concatenating but is possible with `string.Format()` is making the format string a variant (taken from configuration for `I18N` for example).

Pay attention to the capital `T` in the `Text` property.

Comment: if cal is int or double then this won't compile `(string)cal;` Also you forgot to Convert.ToString :p

Comment: I would avoid a no-op format call

Answer (score 1):

Just Use like this

```
textBox4.Text = cal.ToString();
```

## [ToString()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tostring)

```
textBox4.Text=Convert.ToString(cal);

textBox4.Text = new StringBuilder().Append(cal).ToString();

textBox4.Text=Convert.string.Empty + Cal;
```